# Checking if a string is a number with STL

Tags: c++, stl

Recently me and colleague had a discussion about the following piece of code (simple bool function that checks if string is a number, `+1000` not allowed, `-1000`, `1234` ... allowed).

He felt that it was hackish, while I thought it was nice, clean and elegant (since it uses STL, not hand made loops).
So is this a judgement call or one of us is wrong? Is this code elegant or hack?

```
 bool validate(const std::string& m)  
 {
   if (m.empty()) 
     return false;
   return m.end() == find_if(*m.begin() == '-'? ++m.begin() : m.begin(),
                                    m.end(), not1(ptr_fun(isdigit)));
 }
```

Comment: It's not elegant if it has code for special cases (that's part of *my* definition of elegant).

Comment: For somebody unfamiliar with stl, this is unreadable. Simple for loop is easy, and understood by anybody

Comment: It seems pretty darn hard to read to me... I would never do so many things in one statement.

Comment: @elmes:  Even for somebody *extremely* familiar with STL, this is damned hard to read.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approach (i.e. I would find it unsurprising), but apparently I'm the odd one out here...

Comment: @ildjam - yeah, like I said I consider it very elegant. :)

Comment: [Don't cross post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163638/is-this-code-elegant-or-hack#comment14643018_11163638).

Comment: I have nothing against the algorithms. But would be better if you did not try and do it in one line. One list does not equal elegant. Easy to read (at a glance) equal elegant.

Comment: @elmes Irrelevant. Someone unfamiliar with STL doesn’t count for anything. But there are other objections to the code. That it doesn’t work, for instance …).

Answer (score 4):

I had to really look at your code and think about what it was doing before I figured it out.  That tells me that this code is not elegant by my definition of "elegant".  My definition of elegant is something like,

> Easy to understand, easy to maintain, efficient in execution, robust.

I would suggest something like this as a start:

```
if( m.empty() )
  return false;

string::iterator start = m.begin();
if( *start == '-' )
  ++start;

if( m.end() == find_if( start, m_end(), not1(ptr_fun(isdigit)) ))
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

Not much caring for the use of `find_if`, I'd refine it to:

```
if( m.empty() )
  return false;

string::size_type pos = 0;
if( m[0] == '-' )
  pos = 1;

if( m.find_first_not_of("0123456789", pos) == m.end() )
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

I find this to be much more elegant than the 1-liner you wrote.  It's more code, sure.  But it is exceedingly simple to understand and maintain.  You found a bug yourself just by brain-compiling it.  That's what code should look like.

Comment: if i compiled and ran in my head correctly second transformation returns true for "42-1729"

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Edited, please take a look.

Comment: i guess you also need to remove minus from find_first_not_of, but it is just  a minor thing

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl:  Done.

Comment: `if (…) return true; else return false;` is a *huge* antipattern in my book.

Comment: `return ( m.find_first_not_of("0123456789", pos) == m.end() );` would be preferable, imho.

Comment: I personally don't like the `find_first_not_of("0123456789")`. Though I can't actually think of a situation were this would not work correctly, it makes me have a nagging suspicion that there is some corner case (maybe with locals) that may fail. I would prefer the use something standard that actually checks to see if the whole value is a number (like strtol).

Comment: `( m.find_first_not_of("0123456789", pos) == m.end() )` gives me a compile time error: "Invalid operands to binary expression".  This one is good: `( m.find_first_not_of("0123456789", pos) == string::npos )`

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case, pretty much pure C does the job as well as anything:

```
bool check_num(std::string const &in) {
    char *end;

    strtol(in.c_str(), &end, 10);
    return !in.empty() && *end == '\0';
}
```

Comment: Corner case is that std::string allows '\0' within the string. Unlikely to fail but not foolproof.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using `find_if` (fine by me), and not mutating variables (fine by me as well!), your code still suffers from three deficiencies:

1. Too much happening in a single statement. *Separate*.
2. Why `*m.begin()` instead of `m.front()` or even `m[0]`?
3. `++` first and foremost mutates a value. `++m.begin()`, even though it compiles, smells, since we discard the mutated value and just use the value returned by the expression. *This* definitely qualifies as a hack.

But since `string::iterator` is a random-access iterator, you can just write `+ 1`. In cases where that doesn’t work, there’s now [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) which calls `std::advance` internally and returns the modified result.

```
bool validate(const std::string& m)  
{
    if (m.empty()) 
        return false;

    auto begin = m[0] == '-' ? std::next(m.begin()) : m.begin();
    return find_if(begin, m.end(), not1(ptr_fun(is_digit))) == m.end();
}
```

Comment: @3. what variable, string or it returned by m.begin()?    Afaik it modifies iterator, so it is legit.  std::string s="C++11";
 ++s.begin();
 ++s.begin();
 ++s.begin();
 char c=*s.begin();
 assert (c='S');

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I take that objection back partially. However, the operation is still not really meaningful, since `++` *modifies* its argument. But we discard that modified value, since it’s a temporary. This still works since prefix `++` also *returns* the modified value but it’s still not an entirely meaningful operation – the side-effect was just ignored.

Comment: still I dont get your objection, that temporary lives long enough to be used as input param (begin iterator for find_if). So to make it clear is it a stye or correctness objection?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl It’s an objection of style, *not* of correctness (it was initially, but that was my mistake, because the style confused me).

Comment: Ah, just noticed you posted an answer, going for the sane return nonetheless. `if (…) return true; else return false;` made me chuckle.

Comment: I'd use `auto const begin = m.begin() + (m[0] == '-');`,  maybe add a conditional if I didn't want to abuse the implicit conversion to int.

Comment: @AntonGolov Spot-on: I’m against using the implicit `bool <=> int` conversion. Apart from that, adding 1 is of course a good solution (see answer) – I wanted to showcase the general case that also works for non-random-access iterators.

Comment: @AntonGolov: Yep I agree that lines readability can improved with your technique. But I am with Konrad and don;t like the implicit bool -> int conversion. So: `begin = m.begin() + (m[0] == '-') ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: I confess that I do like the implicit conversion to `int`, as long as it's clearly demarcated by parentheses. But then, I'm also very used to the Iverson bracket which I've found to be *incredibly* useful. I think I would prefer an explicit conversion to the conditional, though.